# css 3D transform cube perspective

Tags: css, cube, css-transforms, perspective

I'm trying to create a grid of cubes that have a perspective that looks like you're looking at them from the top. Here is an example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b73k2.jpg

This one is made by calculating how far the cube is from the middle and changing the border size. I want to make my own texture on the sides of the cube so I used CSS3 rotation to create the six sides of the cube and position them correctly to form a cube. Now I tried to recreate the effect by having the cubes tilt over the x and y axis depending on how far they are from the center and i got this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKmwg

As you can see it looks like they're on some kind of spherical surface. This is because the front and back side of the cube should not be rotating. Does anyone know of the proper way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Are the cubes individual elements? What is your `perspective` set to? Have you thought about using [`perspective-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transforms) instead of rotations? How are you performing the rotations? Please share your code if you want more meaningful help.

Comment: Added my code in there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jozzas perspective origin was what i was looking for:

http://codepen.io/avovk/pen/yICrt